# React components not showing up on the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components

I am getting started on Reactjs today to build a login page.

Here is my code:

Login.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Login = (props) => {
    return (<div>Login</div>)
}

export default Login;
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Login from './Login.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/'>
            <Login />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But when I typed 'yarn start' and refresh the page, nothing shows up.

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me where I got wrong.

Comment: Is this react-router 6? If so, you need to do it as `<Route path="/" element={<Login/>}>`. Using children is not supported any more, and `exact` is unnecesary, since it's exact by default. If you want it to be inexact, you opt-in with `path="/*"`

Comment: youtube tutorials outdate pretty quick now a day because things like react-router comes with new syntax every update.